# Avoid RAND() query from slow query log

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization

How to avoid this query to be logged when `--log-queries-not-using-indexes` is turned on?

([source of the query](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/))

```
EXPLAIN SELECT  id,autor,description
FROM    (
        SELECT  @cnt := COUNT(*) + 1,
                @lim := 3
        FROM    testimonale
        ) vars
STRAIGHT_JOIN
        (
        SELECT  r.*,
                @lim := @lim - 1
        FROM    testimonale r
        WHERE   (@cnt := @cnt - 1)
                AND RAND() < @lim / @cnt

        ) i;
```

**EXPLAIN**

```
id  select_type  table       type    possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra                         
1   PRIMARY      <derived2>  system                                    1                                   
1   PRIMARY      <derived3>  ALL                                       3                                   
3   DERIVED      r           ALL                                       8     Using where                   
2   DERIVED                                                                  Select tables optimized away
```

Comment: SET sql_log_bin = 0; query SET sql_log_bin = 1; ?

Comment: can also do SET log_queries_not_using_indexes = 0; and then set it to 1 afterwards instead you may have to look up the actual sql variable name but its something like above.

Comment: Are you asking how to make this query use an index?

Comment: @yak no he's asking now to stop it being logged for being a query not using an index. but maintain logs for all other queries

Comment: @YaK I am asking how to avoid being written into the slow query log file. The query is efficient.

Comment: @Pentium10 its a dynamic variable so can be set on and off at will setting it off then running your query then setting it back on will work according to the mysql website see my comment no2

Comment: I need to investigate as I need the SUPER privilege to do so.

Comment: sorry if I sound stupid, but I do not see the point of the question. You are asking how to have a query not using an index not to be logged when you explicitely set the server to log those queries? Or are you looking for something similar to the [`SQL_NO_CACHE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache-in-select.html) option (but for the slow query log)?

Comment: The query is efficient, there is no need to be logged. We have a large  request/second, and we lose a lot of time just to log a query that takes 0.000045 sec.

Comment: @Dave check the bold section from Yak answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any possibility to disable the logging of individual queries. `log_queries_not_using_indexes` is global and changing it on-the-fly would prevent the logging of any concurrent queries (although I understand this is quite unlikely if the query is that quick).

Since you actually want to lower the load induced by this logging, you may want to play with the [`log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes) (added in v5.6.5 only) or the [`min_examined_row_limit`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_min_examined_row_limit) server options instead.

**The latter exists at session level. It could be increased to an absurdly large value just before your query, with no impact on concurrent connections. Surprisingly, no special privilege is required.**